# IIS: Enable directory listing/browsing for all subfolders of a particular folder

Tags: iis, .htaccess

the aim is to have a folder, e.g. "upload" which is filled with subfolders in an automated process. Now, each of these subfolders should be browsable (i.e. Directory Browsing ON), but not the parent folder ("upload"). How can this be done?

Is there a way to set this within the webserver? Or do I need a script to place the right .htaccess files within the folder?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of IIS are you using?

Comment: I am using IIS 6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you'd just turn on "directory browsing" at the parent directory and allow that to inherit to the child directories. Since you don't want that behaviour, though, you're going to need to modify the IIS metabase (the configuration database where IIS keeps its configuration) for each subdirectory.

In an IIS 6 world (Windows 2003), I'd write a script using the Microsoft-provided "adsutil.vbs" script (in %SystemDrive%\inetpub\adminscripts by default) to create the appropriate metabase entries for each subdirectory. Something like:

```
@echo off 
SET PARENT_DIR=C:\path\to\parent\directory
SET ADSUTIL=cscript C:\inetpub\adminscripts\adsutil.vbs 
SET METABASE_PATH=W3SVC/####/ROOT/path/to/parent/directory

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`dir /a /b /ad %PARENT_DIR%\*`) do call :do_directory "%%i"
goto end

:do_directory
%ADSUTIL% ENUM "%METABASE_PATH%/%~1" | find "IIsWebDirectory"
if errorlevel 1 goto create_directory
goto end

:create_directory
%ADSUTIL% CREATE "%METABASE_PATH%/%~1" "IIsWebDirectory" 
%ADSUTIL% SET "%METABASE_PATH%/%~1/DirBrowseFlags" "3221225534" 
%ADSUTIL% SET "%METABASE_PATH%/%~1/EnableDirBrowsing" "True"
%ADSUTIL% SET "%METABASE_PATH%/%~1/DirBrowseShowDate" "True"
%ADSUTIL% SET "%METABASE_PATH%/%~1/DirBrowseShowTime" "True"
%ADSUTIL% SET "%METABASE_PATH%/%~1/DirBrowseShowSize" "True"
%ADSUTIL% SET "%METABASE_PATH%/%~1/DirBrowseShowExtension" "True"
%ADSUTIL% SET "%METABASE_PATH%/%~1/DirBrowseShowLongDate" "True"
%ADSUTIL% SET "%METABASE_PATH%/%~1/EnableDefaultDoc" "True"

:end
```

Replace #### with the site number and the paths to the appropriate directories.

Comment: Is there any reference material available anywhere for the metabase and what you can modify?